# Profiling code in Android Studio

Tags: debugging, android-studio, ide

I recently started using Android Studio, after a java-hiatus. Eons ago i used NetBeans and one feature i miss is the ability to attach a profiler to my code to see which classes and methods were using the most CPU cycles and RAM. Is there a way of doing this in android studio when I'm working on a project that runs on desktop and not on an android device? Be it natively or via a plugin.